# Why is bitset::set() triggering undefined behavior

Tags: c++, clang++, std-bitset, ubsan

If I compile this code

```
#include <bitset>

int
main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::bitset<96> mask;
    mask.set();
    return 0;
}
```

with `clang++ -fsanitize=integer test_bitset.cpp`
and run the result, I get

```
.../include/c++/12/bitset:657:46: runtime error: left shift of 18446744073709551615 by 32 places cannot be represented in type 'std::_Sanitize::_WordT' (aka 'unsigned long')
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior .../include/c++/12/bitset:657:46 in
```

This looks a little bit like [Why does the clang sanitizer think this left shift of an unsigned number is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73779721/why-does-the-clang-sanitizer-think-this-left-shift-of-an-unsigned-number-is-unde)
but if I try to disable the check using

```
clang++ -fsanitize=integer -fno-sanitize=unsigned-integer-overflow test_bitset.cpp
```

the undefined behavior persists. To add to the confusion, if I enable "all" integer checks manually (as mentioned in [the docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html#available-checks))

```
clang++ -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow,unsigned-integer-overflow,shift,integer-divide-by-zero,implicit-unsigned-integer-truncation,implicit-signed-integer-truncation,implicit-integer-sign-change test_bitset.cpp
```

the undefined behavior is gone. So apparently `-fsanitize=integer` does more than that?

I can silence the error using a blacklist on bitset but I really want to know whether it is a bug in the stdlib or can be ignored safely.

I tried this with clang 14 and clang 15 on a standard ubuntu 22.04. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: The option you want is `-fno-sanitize=unsigned-shift-base`. I guess they forgot to mention it in the `-fsanitize=integer` documentation.

Comment: And it is not a bug in the library. The shift operation has defined behavior. Some of Clang's UBSan checks do however explicitly check for non-UB situations that are often unintentional, but also often intentional if the programmer knows what they are doing. This check is one of them. `-fsanitize=integer` enables multiple of them.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the right option!

Answer (score 0):

As @user17732522 pointed out correctly it is just a bug in the clang docs. The correct call to avoid the check is `clang++  -fsanitize=integer -fno-sanitize=unsigned-shift-base test_bitset.cpp` and the check is just oversensitive it is *not* an undefined behavior.